# How to check if mandatory fields are filled in?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check the my worksheet for text in mandatory fields before I save my file. If cells B50:B53 has a text, corresponding cells D50:D53 are mandatory. If cells B50:B53 are empty, corresponding fields in column D are optional.

If I apply this rule to one row it works with the following code. However, I want to test all cases (B50 and D50, B51 and D51...). How can I do this without copying the code 4 times?

```
Dim MsgStr As String
Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Range, g As Range    

Set ws = wb.Sheets("Allotment hotel")
Set r = ws.Range("B50").Cells
Set g = ws.Range("D50").Cells

If r <> "" And g = "" Then
    MsgStr = "Room type was not found in the sheet 'Allotment hotel'"
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub check()

    Dim msg As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("Allotment hotel").Range("B50:B53")

    For Each cell In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            If IsEmpty(cell.Offset(0, 2)) Then
                msg = "Whatever String you want"
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Or make a Named Range for cells B50:B53, lets call it `checkrng`

```
Set rng = Sheets("Allotment hotel").Range("checkrng")
```